# NSTemporaryDirectory subdirectories

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsurl, nsfilemanager

I can't store any file  in NSTemporaryDirectory subfolders

rootDirectoryName is GUID
subDirectoryName is also a GUID

```
self.rootFolderPath=[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:rootDirectoryName];
self.currentFolder=[self.rootFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:subDirectoryName];
NSURL* url =[NSURL URLWithString:[self.currentFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:path]];
[data writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray* paths=[fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:self.currentFolder error:nil];
```

where path is also some GUID.jpg
I'm trying to save jpg data.

every time paths array is empty.
Before this i create a rootDirectoryName and  subDirectoryName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Just replaced `[data writeToURL:url atomically:YES]` to 
`[data writeToFile:[url path] atomically:YES]`.